# iOS Calling Phone Number from NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to store a phone number as an NSString in NSUserDefaults. For some reason the code below does not work. The code works if I do not use a variable, but I cannot get it to work. Does anyone have any ideas why?

```
NSString *savedPhone = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                        stringForKey:@"savedPhone"];

NSString *callNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"tel://",savedPhone];

NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:callNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve with below code:

```
NSUserDefaults *objUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedPhone = [objUserDefaults objectForKey:@"savedPhone"];
[self callNumber:savedPhone];
```

Then add below function:

```
-(void)callNumber:(NSString *)pstrContactNo
{
    NSString *strDeviceModel = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if(![strDeviceModel isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
    {
            UIAlertView *objAlertMsg = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                       message:@"Calling is not supported in this device."
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [objAlertMsg show];
       [objAlertMsg release];
    }
    else
    {
        pstrContactNo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",pstrContactNo];
        NSString *strDialedContact = [pstrContactNo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strDialedContact]];
    }
}
```

This will resolve your issue.

Cheers!

Comment: See @Oleg answer you should remove the `//` in the `tel:` scheme. Also it is better the do check if the device supports the `tel:`scheme then to check wheter the device model is an iPhone. Just use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:"]`

Comment: @rckoenes: answer is not accepted. Then why you have down the answer?? This is also tested code. Don't know.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. I was merely trying to tell you that you answer had some error in it.

Comment: Then who can be, may be someone wants that, his/her answer should be accepted. And they have down vote my properly formatted answer. Very Bad.

Answer (score 1):

Change your URL format (remove `//`)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:2135554321"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `callNumber` like this:
NSString *callNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",savedPhone];

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *number = YOUR-NUMBER;       
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",number]];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Try with this code, it will navigate back to your app after finished call